# from suds.client import Client failed

Tags: python, wcf, suds

I just learn python for not a long time. When I try to use python to write a WCF client, I failed at the start up. 
just type the command at python shell:

```
 from suds.client import Client
```

it failed with:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 242
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to **update suds or install suds for python3**. You are currently using suds for python2

**[Suds Python3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-py3):**

Comment: Yes you are right, I  tried with suds for python3 , then it works now.